# installed mamp on lion server - how to access the mamp sites and not the lion server ones?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, macos, mamp

I just installed MAMP and wordpress on a lion server. I can access my wordpress installation when in the server at the folder Applications/Mamp/htdocs/wordpress via the URL localhost/wordpress

When I try to access it from another computer on another network, I get URL not found.
When I put the IP 172.168.1.24 at the URL I get to the Lion server (/Library/Server/...) and not the Mamp one.

Any idea how to override that and get directly to the Mamp server?

Thanks!

Comment: `localhost` == 127.0.0.1. probably mamp is bound to 127.0.0.1, and lionserver is bound to the public IP

Comment: maybe a better fit on server or superuser... because you could set it up many different ways... you could listen to a different port, or ip/name; or you could run one in front of the other, proxying to another port... there are many many options.